# Spotting strings that are typos in "text mode" but that are right in "math mode"

Tags: l3regex, xesearch, research

My copy editor work is largely dedicate do spot typos. I have a kind of typos formed by strings like, e.g., "`.`",  "`,`", "`:`"...  (a space before a punctuation sign) that we consider typos in text-mode (e.g. "as follow :") but aren't a problem inside in-line math or math environments (e.g. "$\mu .$").

Usually we use custom emacs' query-replace regexp to find and correct these typos but, as emacs doesn't distinguish math mode from text mode (I know, I can do some tricks to do that but it is not a robust solution), I typically have a lot of false positives (and this is very boring).

I was wondering if there is a native LaTeX solution to do that. I mean not the query-replace but to highlight some matched strings.

I found, e.g., the `xesearch` package but it doesn't handle punctuation search.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Punctuation , typos .

No problem with this string
\begin{equation}
(\mu + \nu) ,
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I also found `l3regex` but I think it performs regexp works on the LaTeX code and not on the pre-formatted code as `xesearch` does.

Any hints, suggestions or helpful ideas are welcome.

**Edit.** As I answered in comments: "I'm asking for a technique to distinguish strings that are in math mode from strings that are in text mode and highlight only the second ones".

**Edit 2.** I moved and posted a related question here: [XeTeXinterchartoks: Why the “)” in the layout of “\eqref” and (\ref{…}) are interpreted differently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410999/33634)

Comment: `$\mu ,$` is wrong anyway. In my experience, errors like these are so various that finding a catch-all regex is hopeless. And `l3regex` (now in the L3 kernel) is not related.

Comment: @egreg Obviously I'm not asking for a catch-all regex! ;-) I'm  asking for a technique to distinguish strings that are in math mode from strings that are in text mode and highlight only the second ones.

Comment: Just so we understand, you are asking for an editor function, rather than a LaTeX function.  The answer if it exists will, obviously, be editor specific.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm asking for both things. I use emacs as editor and I can use features like `syntax-table` or `fontification` to do some tricks but I imagine that only LaTeX can exactly tell if a string is in tex or math mode. Also a viewer allowing regex search would be helpful (but I know this is very tricky)

Comment: [ChkTex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chktex?lang=en) picks up this and several other related errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use xelatex and `\XeTeXinterchartoks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newXeTeXintercharclass\mypunctclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\. \mypunctclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\, \mypunctclass
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \mypunctclass{\textcolor{red}{TYPO}}



\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Punctuation , typos .

Punctuation, typos.

No problem with this string
\begin{equation}
(\mu + \nu) ,
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get:
`! Bad register code (4095).
l.9 \XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 
                             \mypunctclass{\textcolor{red}{TYPO}}` 
Do I need to upgrade mi TexLive version?
`pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)`

Comment: You have an older xetex, change the number to 255 (or update your system).

Comment: I tried with 255 but I got: `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]`.

Comment: Hm. Looks as if doesn't like the color. It works with `\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \mypunctclass{TYPO}`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This solution seems very promising. Where  can I get the infos to learn about this feature of xelatex. I'd like to learn how to create other highlights by myself (e.g. for strings like "( ", " ]" or " ?"... so to have the complete set of punctuation errors. I programmed to update my TexLive in September.

Comment: Simply search this site for e.g. \XeTeXinterchartokenstate. There are enough examples.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please I'd like to know just one more things. Is it possible to have the strings "( ", and " )" the same time? I just need a yes or not answer.

Comment: Sure. You can add them to the class. `\XeTeXcharclass `\( \mypunctclass`. The main idea is to put glyphs in one (or more) classes, and then to define what should happen between two classes. 255/4095 is the "word boundary class".

Comment: I get false positives in a lot of cases: `\cite{bib1},`, `$x$,` `\emph{word},`, `eqref{eq1},` etc.  Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 10):

In keeping with the Carlisle tradition, I am naming this "gem" `\z`.  Done here for commas, periods and colons, but added loops could be set up for other tests.

I would be remiss if I didn't draw your attention to Ulrike's comments, noting that there are many pitfalls for `\z`.  For example `verbatim` material, as well as the occurrence of the offending syntax inside a valid argument list are likely to cause compilation errors.

EDITED so that it can now work when the offending bit falls, for example, inside an `align` environment.  Rather than outputting the parts on the fly (which causes problems if the offending bit falls inside an argument), I instead create a concatenated `\def` in which every `.`, etc. is replaced with an `\ifmmode{} .\else\colorbox{cyan}{ .}\fi` inside the `\def`.  Only at the end, is the `def`ed macro named `\z@save` regurgitated.  [Just for completeness, the original behavior can be obtained by defining `\newcommand\zz@[1]{#1}` instead of the revised `\newcommand\zz@[1]{\g@addto@macro\z@save{#1}}` ]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\z[1]{\def\z@save{}\z@A#1 ,\z@end\z@save}
\long\def\z@A#1 ,#2\z@end{%
  \z@B#1 .\z@end%
  \ifx\z@end#2\else\zz@{\ifmmode{} ,\else\colorbox{cyan}{ ,}\fi}\z@A#2\z@end\fi}
\long\def\z@B#1 .#2\z@end{%
  \z@C#1 :\z@end%
  \ifx\z@end#2\else\zz@{\ifmmode{} .\else\colorbox{orange}{ .}\fi}\z@B#2\z@end\fi}
\long\def\z@C#1 :#2\z@end{%
  \zz@{#1}%
  \ifx\z@end#2\else\zz@{\ifmmode{} :\else\colorbox{yellow}{ :}\fi}\z@C#2\z@end\fi}
\newcommand\zz@[1]{\g@addto@macro\z@save{#1}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\z{
Punctuation , typos : such as 3 .75 and such .

No problem with this string
\begin{equation}
(3 .7\mu + \nu) ,
\end{equation}

\begin{align} 
\mathcal{A}_{\text{reg}}:\qquad ( - l_u/2+\epsilon_u , - l_\phi/2+\epsilon_\phi ) 
  \rightarrow ( l_u/2-\epsilon_u , l_\phi/2-\epsilon_\phi )\,. \end{align}
And again , are there these problems : a nd b .
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is impressive, but wouldn't this be more conveniently handled in LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @JPi If only I knew lualatex...

Comment: I tried your code on a long paper: no punctuation errors.... :-)

Comment: Wow. A whole document body in an argument.  It better shouldn't contain verbatim material, or tikz pictures, or keyval arguments with spaces. Try e.g. `\num[group-digit , groupseparator= . ]{123456}`.

Comment: Ok, It works with small files but when I wrap a 3000 lines long `.tex` file someting goes wrong. I have this error:
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd) [5] [6] [7]
[8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.3066 }\end{document}

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi This isn't unexpected, I'm more surprised that it worked for 13 pages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you think that it could be fixed?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Well, i was worried about blowing up the stack for large files, but I don't think that it would produce that error, if I did.  More likely, the occurrence of, for example, ` .` is occurring in the argument of a macro and then the macro doesn't know how to digest a `\colorbox` in the middle of it.  One test would be to replace `\colorbox{ .}` type calls with ` *` or even ` .`  just to see if it then compiles.  The other thing is to reduce the argument size of `\z` until you find the actual bit of code that is choking it.  Then I could reexamine it.

Comment: Mine worked for a complex 40 page paper.  The only downside is that it killed synctex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Obviously, it requires some user intervention to exclude such areas of a document.  But, then, you might reply, the cure is worse than the ailment.  Point taken.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Take note also of Ulrike's comments.  There are certain things, like `verbatim` and even argument lists where the problem in digesting it with `\z` will occur.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I understood the Ulrike's comment. But code that cause the error is this:
`\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}_{\text{reg}}:\qquad (  - l_u/2+\epsilon_u ,  - l_\phi/2+\epsilon_\phi  ) \rightarrow (  l_u/2-\epsilon_u , l_\phi/2-\epsilon_\phi )\,.
\end{align}`
If I remove space before "," the error disappears.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Please see my revision.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Now it works. Thanks! This is a big step forward! But I'll wait for possible more compete solutions before accepting your answer. ;-)