# XeTeXinterchartoks: Why the ")" in the layout of "\eqref" and (\ref{...}) are interpreted differently?

Tags: xetex

Related to my previous question: [Spotting strings that are typos in “text mode” but that are right in “math mode”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383513/33634) I have this code (I'll write the complete example to better claryfy the question):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newXeTeXintercharclass\mypunctclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\. \mypunctclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\, \mypunctclass
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \mypunctclass{\textcolor{red}{TYPO}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Punctuation , typos .

Punctuation, typos.

\paragraph{False positives:}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  $1$,
\item \eqref{eq1}, (but this is not a problem: (\ref{eq1}),)

\item \emph{word},

\end{itemize}
No problem with this string
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
(\mu + \nu) ,
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My question is: why `\XeTeXinterchartoks` behaves differently with `\eqref{eq1},` and `(\ref{eq1}),`? (But also with `word,` and `\emph{word},` etc.)

Comment: The problem is that the "boundary" contains more than glue, but also "kern, math, box" (see the xetex-reference). So I don't think that you can avoid these false positives.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I could redefine all macros that generates false positives surronding them with `()` this way: `\def\eqref#1{(\ref{#1})}`, `\let\Oldemph\emph
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{(\Oldemph{#1})}` etc. But I have no idea ho to fix the `$something$` case... Very overkill... I know, but that should work.